# Element in the body section of html to be at the top of the page, while all other elements are at the center

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS. In my body section, I had a div with a bunch of elements inside that was in the middle of the page. I attempted to add a header with a navbar and logo to the body, but I cannot figure out how to place the header at the top of the page while keeping the div in the middle.

Here's the HTML &  CSS code for the body (contains the div and header), the div (called container), and the header

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #03a9f4;
  transition: 1s;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help Listings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button class="cta">Contact</button>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box signin">
    <h2>Already Have An Account?</h2>
    <button class="signinBtn">Sign In</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box signup">
    <h2>Don't Have An Account?</h2>
    <button class="signupBtn">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="formBx">
    <div class="form signinform">
      <form>
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot Password</a>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form signupform">
      <form>
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
        <!-- give a warning if the user has caps lock on -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

How do I put the logo, navbar, and contact buttons at the top of the page while keeping the sign-in box in the middle?

Comment: Please provide a [repro] for debugging details. We neither can debug CSS without its HTML markup nor debug pictures. Also using `display: flex` on a body is in general a bad idea with certain exceptions (unless you change the default flex direction to column).

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the html code for the body and other elements. Also, why is using display: flex on a body typically a bad idea?

Comment: because display flex by default will align all elements in one row and start squishing them to fit the row. Most content will not fit that way or will be terribly aligned. You should remain the default block-level behavior which at least requires the usage of `flex-direction: column`

Comment: Ah,  see. But now the header is directly above the div instead of the top of the page (I re-edited the post to display this). How do I fix this?

Comment: one way you could start is using `body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 100vh; } .container { flex-grow: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; align-items: center; }`  and check what it does for you. That should already fix your major problem and you should be able to finish from there

Comment: I have something that works but I want to move the div slightly down without changing it, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `position` of the header to `absolute` will bring it out of the normal document flow and then `top: 0` will put it at the top.

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #03a9f4;
  transition: 1s;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help Listings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button class="cta">Contact</button>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box signin">
    <h2>Already Have An Account?</h2>
    <button class="signinBtn">Sign In</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box signup">
    <h2>Don't Have An Account?</h2>
    <button class="signupBtn">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="formBx">
    <div class="form signinform">
      <form>
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot Password</a>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form signupform">
      <form>
        <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
        <!-- give a warning if the user has caps lock on -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: asking for answers to be upvoted or checked is not allowed

Comment: Can you share the link where I can find this rule as well as any other such rules so that I can follow ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403392/is-it-ok-to-leave-a-comment-asking-for-upvotes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: OK, thanks. Will follow. Suggesting new users to "Accept Answer" when it is helpful is allowed but upvoting is not. I didn't know this one.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of CSS `flexbox` properties for the desired layout. Such as :

It will resolve your issue.

```
 body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; 
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #03a9f4;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 800px;
        height: 400px;
flex-direction: row-reverse; 
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
    header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 30px 10%;
        }


And in the body add:

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the question was not designing a navbar. Using float to align items next to each other is a misused hack that isn't necessary anymore since 2012. The modern and clean solutions use flexbox. A good example will Frontend experts recommend not to use w3school for learning purposes as most articles are outdated and teach bad coding methods.